# Do analog mixers boost mic level to line level?

Tags: mixer, microphone, line-level

Does your typical analog non-powered mixer boost the mic inputs to line level for all the signal processing ie. effects, eq, panning, or does it remain mic level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all mixers work at line level, although what everyone classes as line level is not the same.  Pro line level = +4 dBu and consumer line level = -10 dBu.

Comment: So most high end analog mixers will have pre-amps for the mic in to boost it to +4 dBu?

Comment: Yes almost all modern high-end analogue mixers with mic pre-amps will work at +4 dBu.

There are professional line mixers that do not contain any mic pre-amps at all though.  These 'summing' mixers are used to generate harmonics during a final mix down, or for line level sources such as musical keyboards. 

Answer (score 1):

generally anything with a preamp moves signal from mic level to line level.

Comment: yes, should have specified.  mic pre.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a "non-powered mixer" that handles amplification from mic to line level. Hell, I haven't even really heard of many (if any) "non-powered" mixers to begin with. amplifiers need both a signal source, and a power supply.

Do you have a particular model your thinking of? Because this question honestly doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Oh sorry I was just trying to be specific. When I said non-powered meant mixer that sends line level to the powered speakers witch then amplify that. As opposed to powered mixer like where the amplification takes place in the mixer itself. Like- http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/EMX312SC?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=none&gclid=CPi0uMCEvagCFWUbQgodSXHcCA
for example.

Comment: ahh...ok. if you want a basic understanding of the signal flow through a channel of a mixer, just start at the top and work your way down. the top most item is a gain/trim pot. any mic input is going to first be brought up to line level before passing through the rest of the circuitry in the channel.